# DirectX vertices for heightmap from tri list to tri strip

Tags: c++, directx

I have a program that loads in a heightmap, I then sort the vertices out to an array using the triangle list method, my question is how would i go about changing it to triangle strip? I want it to be one strip so the first row would be left to right, second row right to left etc doing this using for loops.

My code for the trianlge list method so far (not showing heightmap loader or number of vertices definition, also showing the normals calculator but i dont need any help adapting that):

```
for( int l = 0; l < m_HeightMapLength; ++l )
{
    for( int w = 0; w < m_HeightMapWidth; ++w )
    {   
        if( w < m_HeightMapWidth-1 && l < m_HeightMapLength-1 )
        {
            /*v0 = m_pHeightMap[mapIndex];
            v1 = m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+m_HeightMapWidth];
            v2 = m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1];
            v3 = m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+m_HeightMapWidth+1];

            D3DXVECTOR3 vA = v0 - v1;
            D3DXVECTOR3 vB = v1 - v2;
            D3DXVECTOR3 vC = v3 - v1;

            D3DXVECTOR3 vN1;
            D3DXVec3Cross(&vN1, &vA, &vB);
            D3DXVECTOR3 vN2;
            D3DXVec3Cross(&vN2, &vB, &vC);*/

            //D3DXVec3Normalize( &vN1, &vN1);
            //D3DXVec3Normalize( &vN2, &vN2);

            //T Left, Bot Left, T Right, T Right, Bot Left, Bot Right
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN1.x, vN1.y, vN1.z));
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN1.x, vN1.y, vN1.z));
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN1.x, vN1.y, vN1.z));
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex+1].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN2.x,  vN2.y, vN2.z));
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN2.x,  vN2.y, vN2.z));
            //m_pMapVtxs[i++] = Vertex_Pos3fColour4ubNormal3f(D3DXVECTOR3( m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth+1].x, m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth+1].y,  m_pHeightMap[mapIndex + m_HeightMapWidth+1].z), MAP_COLOUR, D3DXVECTOR3(vN2.x,  vN2.y, vN2.z));
```

mapIndex++;

The for loops is my main problem to change it to strip, i already have the vertices mapped out on paper so thats my main problem, any insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `m_pHeightMap` is a 3d vector.

The strip will look like this:

```
+--+--+--+--+
|/ |/ |/ |/ |
+--+--+--+--+
| \| \| \| \|
+--+--+--+--+
```

We'll start at the bottom left corner, continue to the right, then one row up and continue to the left. But let's have a look at how to define a strip for a single row first:

```
for(int x = 0; i < m_HeightMapWidth; ++x)
{
    add m_pHeightMap[x + y * m_HeightMapWidth]; //bottom vertex
    add m_pHeightMap[x + (y + 1) * m_HeightMapWidth]; //top vertex
}
```

This works for every second row. The last vertex will be the row's top right vertex. There, we have to add a degenerated triangle. This is a triangle with the area 0 and will cause the rows to be separated. So:

```
add m_pHeightMap[m_HeightMapWidth + m_HeightMapWidth - 1]; //once again the last vertex
```

And for the row above that we add the vertices from right to left:

```
for(int x = m_HeightMapWidth - 1; i >= 0; --x)
{
    add m_pHeightMap[x + y * m_HeightMapWidth]; //bottom vertex
    add m_pHeightMap[x + (y + 1 ) * m_HeightMapWidth]; //top vertex
}
```

Note that the first vertex is the one we already added twice. Adding it a third time will preserve the triangles' orientation.

And we do this for each row. So alltogether:

```
for(int y = 0; y < m_HeightMapHeight - 1; ++y)
{
    if(y % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int x = 0; i < m_HeightMapWidth; ++x)
        {
            add m_pHeightMap[x + y * m_HeightMapWidth]; //bottom vertex
            add m_pHeightMap[x + (y + 1) * m_HeightMapWidth]; //top vertex
        }
        add m_pHeightMap[(y + 2) * m_HeightMapWidth - 1]; //once again the last vertex
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x = m_HeightMapWidth - 1; i >= 0; --x)
        {
            add m_pHeightMap[x + y * m_HeightMapWidth]; //bottom vertex
            add m_pHeightMap[x + (y + 1 ) * m_HeightMapWidth]; //top vertex
        }
        add m_pHeightMap[(y + 1) * m_HeightMapWidth]; //once again the last vertex
    }
}
```

* The code is untested

Comment: With a slight bit of tweaking it fundamentaly works, now to sort the normals. Thank You